# Wordpress - Why can't I use conditional tags inside plugins?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```
if( is_home() ):
    echo 'User is on the homepage.';
else:
    echo 'User is not on the homepage';
endif;
```

If I place it in the themes header or footer then it works but if I place it in my plugin, it doesn't work. I've tried `is_single()` and `is_page()` too and they don't work inside the plugin. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

`is_home()` and several other WP functions are not always defined, Try use a suitable `hook` to include your code. Example:

```
add_action('wp', 'check_home');
// or add_action('init', 'check_home');

function check_home($param)
{
    if (is_home()):
        echo 'User is on the homepage.';
    else:
        echo 'User is not on the homepage';
    endif;
}
```

**EDIT:**

In any case, if you want to echo data use a hook inside the `body` tag. Example using `the_content` hook:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'check_home');

function check_home($content)
{
    if (is_home())
        $echo    = 'User is on the homepage.';
    else
        $echo    = 'User is not on the homepage';

    return $echo . '<hr />' . $content;
}
```